# Remove all rows containing certain strings in R

Tags: r, string

I want to remove all rows from a data frame that contain certain strings. The strings - call them "abc1", "abc2", "abc3" and so forth - appear under different columns at different rows in the dataset. For example, "abc1" may appear in the first column at row 15, and then appear in the second column at row 20. I want to delete all rows that contain any of these strings. The solutions I looked on were based on a single variable containing the strings in question - how do I do this efficiently when the strings appear under more than one variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `filter` with `if_any` to loop over the character class columns, check whether the elements have abc followed by any digits with `str_detect`, negate (`!`) so that we return rows without any of those elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   filter(!if_any(where(is.character), ~ str_detect(.x, "^abc\\d+")))
```

-output

```
   col1 col2 col3
1  ac2    3   5d
2   4d    4   3c
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df1, !Reduce(`|`, lapply(Filter(is.character, df1),
    grepl, pattern = "^abc\\d+")))
  col1 col2 col3
3  ac2    3   5d
4   4d    4   3c
```

---

Or may also do

```
subset(df1, !grepl("abc\\d+", do.call(paste, df1)))
  col1 col2 col3
3  ac2    3   5d
4   4d    4   3c
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("abc1", "xyz1", "ac2", "4d"), col2 = 1:4, 
    col3 = c("1d", "abc3", "5d", "3c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: The code doesn't finish executing when I use it: there is a + sign in the console after I enter the code. I'm typing:

`hier1929 %>% filter(!if_any(where(is.character), ~ str_detect(hier1929, "do from cuba"))`

Comment: @SaunokChakrabarty that is a console symbol.  I double checked.  All the codes I showed are working with the data I created.

Comment: I'm getting the following error. My data frame is named hier1929, and I'm trying to remove rows that contain "do from cuba" (among other strings):

Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `!if_any(where(is.character), ~str_detect(hier1929, "do from cuba"))`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 6291 or 1, not size 48.

Comment: @SaunokChakrabarty in your first code, i think you need a closing `)` at the end

Comment: i.e. just check the number of closing brackets in my code `str_detect(.x, "^abc\\d+")))`